# How can I change the color of the >< remote icon in the VS Code status bar?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I installed the VS Code [Remote Development extensions](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/remote-overview) but the green `><` icon in the left of the status bar doesn't look good with my preferred theme. How do I change its color?

[image: The green >< icon in the status bar]

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The `><` icon is the Remote Window Indicator. [Color themes](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color) can customize its color using the `statusBarItem.remoteBackground` and `statusBarItem.remoteForeground` theme colors

You can also override the color using the [`workbench.colorCustomizations`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color) [setting](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings) in VS Code:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "statusBarItem.remoteBackground": "#5a34a0",
    "statusBarItem.remoteForeground": "#ccc"
}
```

[image: Purple remote indicator]