# VScode: Different color got remote ">< " icon for different servers

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

Similar to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55958171/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-the-remote-icon-in-the-vs-code-status-bar) I want to change the color of the >< icon ([see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kl5ob.png)). Howevever, I want a different color for each server. Say I have `serverA` and `serverB` (lets say WSL) then I want some color for the `><` icon in the window for `serverA` and another color (any random color) for the `><` icon in the window for `serverB`. Is this even possible? Or does the color have to be the same for all servers?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Peacock](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=johnpapa.vscode-peacock) extension